# Listen to field value change with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the postcode anywhere api to populate some address fields. I'm trying to detect the a change of a hidden field value when an address is populated. However, the following just presents an alert when the page loads (the field is blank) and doesn't trigger when the hidden field is populated. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery("#input_42_80").change(function(){
    alert("Test");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to trigger a `change` event after changing the value of the element. Just chain the `.change()` method after modifying the value. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/Le20ycqp/)

For instance:

```
$("#input_42_80").val('changed val').change();
```

..or:

```
$("#input_42_80").val('changed val').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is still not working as expected. The alert is still triggered when the page loads and doesn't trigger when the field value changes. To be clear, #input_42_80 is a hidden field that is populated dynamically from data from address lookup api. I want to trigger the alert only when #input_42_80 value changes